# How to open secondary Skype in version 8.0 +?

Tags: skype

In previous versions of Skype, we can login to multiple Skype accounts from the same pc via "skype.exe /secondary" command. But how to do this in Skype 8.0+?

If it is not possible then please provide any alternative way.

I am currently using windows 10 (desktop) operating system and I am talking about skype desktop client.

Comment: What operating system?  Are we talking about the desktop client or the UWP client?  Edit your question,.do not submit this information, as a comment

Comment: This new version don't have this feature at this moment. Skype Version 8.13.0.3

Comment: Please don't forget to do +1 if you find question useful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On your shortcut file properties, instead of `/secondary` enter the following value:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\Skype.exe" --secondary --datapath "%appdata%\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\profile1"`
```

You can change `profile1` to your liking. It will be the storage of info for each extra skype account you'll want to access at the same time.

source: [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_windesk-skype_startms-skype_signms/how-can-i-run-multiple-skype-812014-accounts-at/c64540e4-20b5-4a78-a039-fd8ab2c59624)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful!