# Is it still possible to run two Skype accounts on the new Windows App version of Skype? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, skype, windows-store-app

As documented over here: [How to run two Skype accounts at the same time in Windows-10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1201513/how-to-run-two-skype-accounts-at-the-same-time-in-windows-10), it used to be possible to run 2 Skype EXEs simultaneously with separate accounts.

Skype got bought and re-written by Microsoft, who turned it into a Windows App, and the old EXE is no longer capable of running.

I can't find an exe associated with the Windows App, so I can't try running it with a `/secondary` flag.
Is it still possible to have 2 Skype accounts active on a single PC, in the ***new*** Skype App?

Answer (score 1):

The
[documentation](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa829/can-i-run-multiple-skype-accounts-at-the-same-time)
advises using
[Skype for Web](https://web.skype.com/).
This way, you only need two browser sessions.

Otherwise, you could install
[Skype for Desktop](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/download-skype-for-desktop/).
You would find the `.exe` in the folders:

- 32-bit version : `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\skype.exe" /Secondary`
- 64-bit version : `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\skype.exe" /secondary`

The above might have changed slightly. See the post
[How to open secondary Skype in version 8.0 +?](https://superuser.com/questions/1272809/how-to-open-secondary-skype-in-version-8-0)